# Using Cloud Firestore Database To Target FCM

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I fear this is pretty simple and I just haven't found the right resource to answer my question.

My app has a simple registration form that collects a few pieces of data and creates a User document in the Cloud Firestore.

```
username: "testuser@email.com"
favoritecolor: "blue"
favoritefood: "pizza"
```

Is there a way to use the information stored in the documents to target specific groups through the Cloud Messaging? For example, if I wanted to target a push notification to users who like pizza and the color blue. I know subscribing the user to topics would work, but I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: Is "subscribing the user to a topic" work? If yes, why not using it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the document https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?, there is a table “Key capabilities” which make mention of the capability “Versatile message targeting” which I think is what you are looking for. Is mentioned there that you can send messages via  Firebase Admin SDK or the FCM server protocols.